# nested loops reversing counter position

Tags: java

Hey guys I've just learnt how to do nested loops. Heres what I've done.

```
public class TEst_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int max = 10;

    for (int row = 1; row <= max; row++) {
        for (int col = 1; col <= row; col++)
            System.out.print(col);

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

I printed the 'col' to get each row to count up to the 10 which i thought was pretty sweet!

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
12345678910
```

I have one question though, how would i go about reversing the numbers? what I mean is counting the column from the right.

```
1
21
321
4321
54321
654321
7654321
87654321
987654321
10987654321
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse count in your inner loop:

```
for (int col = row; col > 0; col--)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with the highest number and decrement until you reach the lowest number.

```
for (int col = row; col >= 1; col--)
```

Comment: Oh! I get the logic now. I very much appreciate the help.